# How to set a default value using Select?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How to set a default value using the select event? Currently in EDIT mode I just hardcoded `selectedKey="USD"`, thus when the user clicks on another value (eg: `CAD`) it does not update the value to `CAD` in the VIEW mode.

```
<Select id="idCurrency" items="{/VH_CurrencySet}" selectedKey="USD">
    <items>
        <core:Item text="{Text}" key="{Code}" />
    </items>
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="XL2 L3 M3 S5" />
    </layoutData>
</Select>
```

In VIEW Mode, the currency should appear as `CAD`.

Comment: hmm can you clarify your question a bit? by assigning `selectedKey` you are setting a default value (IF of course there is an item with Code = 'USD'). If Two-way binding is enabled (default setting so i assume yes), the moment you select CAD, the selectedKey will be updated to CAD.

Does your model have a record with Code = CAD?

Comment: Hi, it does has "CAD" in oData. The currency keep on displaying "USD" even after i select "CAD". Probably because i hardcoded "selectedKey="USD".

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "view mode" and "edit mode"? Is this select part of some form that toggles between view and edit? With your current code, I cannot repro the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/fm7c36e8/

Comment: This part is from Edit Mode. The View Mode, is just basically display the currency.

Comment: I get that, but still a bit unsure how you go between them (you may want to [edit] the question and expand on this). Is it [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/1mj3qxLb/)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a change function for the control:

```
<Select id="idCurrency" items="{/VH_CurrencySet}" selectedKey="USD" change="yourfunction">
    <items>
        <core:Item text="{Text}" key="{Code}"/>
    </items>
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="XL2 L3 M3 S5"/>
    </layoutData>
</Select>
```

After that you implement the `yourfunction` function inside your controller.

Comment: I'm still new to this. Is the change function can be used when I'm using oData? since I only used change when using Json only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I prefer to leverage binding as much as possible.

If you add an entry in your model '/CurrencySelected', the selected value will be reflected in your model permanently.

> controller.js

```
// somewhere on model init
// If you want to keep USD as default value, otherwise first one will be affected automatically
model.setProperty('/CurrencySelected', 'USD')

// To consume the currency
const currentCurrency = model.getProperty('/CurrencySelected')
```

> view.xml

```
<Select 
  id="idCurrency"
  items="{/VH_CurrencySet}"
  selectedKey="{/CurrencySelected}">
  <items>
    <core:Item
      text="{Text}"
      key="{Code}"/>
  </items>
  <layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="XL2 L3 M3 S5"/>
  </layoutData>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right - you shouldn't hard code the Selected Key.
You should set the Selected Key in code once the data has been loaded (e.g. by attaching a function to the attachRequestCompleted event off the model you are loading)
This means that USD would be the initial **default** value only.

After that, the Select control would display the Currency you select.
Trust this makes sense?

```
<Select id="idCurrency" items="{/VH_CurrencySet}">
    <items>
         <core:Item text="{Text}" key="{Code}"/>
    </items>
</Select>
```

If you need access to the currency code you could bind a variable to the selectedKey.